# Why Android Studio cannot find dependices specified in build.gradle file?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Android Beginner here please be nice!

I'm just trying to make an Android App and I have included some dependencies that I though they could help me to achieve my goal. Surprisingly Android Studio is not finding and complaining about the dependencies when trying to build the project as an APK App.

I left pretty much default but this is my `build.gradle(:app)` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.spambuster'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.newapp"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05"
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

I have tried and searched about this error but couldn't find a solution! Here's the error when  I'm trying to build it into an APK:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebugUnitTest, :app:assembleDebugAndroidTest] in project C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp

> Task :app:createDebugVariantModel
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:packageDebugResources
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
> Task :app:assembleDebugUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild SKIPPED
> Task :app:checkDebugAndroidTestAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
> Task :app:mapDebugAndroidTestSourceSetPaths
> Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
> Task :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebugAndroidTest
> Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestJniLibFolders
> Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:desugarDebugAndroidTestFileDependencies FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebugAndroidTest
> Task :app:writeDebugAndroidTestSigningConfigVersions

FAILURE: Build completed with 13 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

9: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAndroidTestAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

10: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

11: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

12: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

13: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugAndroidTestFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-compose-runtime/2.4.0-alpha05/navigation-compose-runtime-2.4.0-alpha05.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime:2.4.0-alpha05"
```

The first two lines are duplicates — you only need one.

There is [no artifact named `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose-runtime`](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.navigation). I do not know where you got that line from. I recommend removing it.

Comment: Yes you are right my friend! I checked on Maven repositories and there was no `navigation-compose-runtime` but instead was `navigation-runtime` and it was in beta version. I replaced that and fixed the problem. Btw thank you for the duplicating line I didn't notice it at first!

Comment: @JugertMucoimaj - what makes you think you need an explicit dependency on `navigation-runtime` anyways? You don't need that (you'll get what you need automatically via `navigation-compose`).

Comment: @ianhanniballake im sorry bro im really trying to learn! maybe it isn't necessary but I didn't know that...

Comment: @JugertMucoimaj - I'm more curious if you saw some documentation or guide that should be updated since the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#setup) seem to be correct.